# In a DataTable object, how do I store an array of strings in each cell of a specific column?

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable

For example, if each row of the data table holds information about an employee, one column might hold a string for their names, one column might hold a string for their phone numbers, and one column might be for their tasks. If an employee has multiple tasks, how can I store an array of strings that represents each task in that particular data cell?

Comment: Why you want use DataTable for storing data about employees?

Comment: I would recommend using a custom object to model this hierarchy instead

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I was looking to bind the table to GridView in ASP.net so that I can have the data display on a webpage, but so that I can also store the string array that holds the tasks in a drop down list on that GridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use string.Join() on your array, and specify the delimiter to use between each array entry.

When you read it back out you can then split it back into an array.

Here is a quick and dirty bit of code that shows how to do it:

```
var tasks = new[] {"Boss", "Secretary", "Tea Lady"};

var joined = string.Join(", ", tasks);

var splitAgain = joined.Split(new[]{", "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: I ended up using this idea! But I stored the information in an asp.net table. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use DataTable I would either combine multiple DataTables into a DataSet... or store this in xml format in a column